# Loading brotli compressed WASM

Tags: go, webassembly, go-wasm

I have a brotli compressed WASM file `main.wasm.br`. I have compressed this manually via CLI.

Currently in my HTML file I have below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Go WASM</title>
    <script src="wasm_exec.js"></script>
    <script>
        const go = new Go();
        WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("main.wasm"), go.importObject).then((result) => {
            go.run(result.instance);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

This loads the uncompressed WASM file. If I change this to `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch("main.wasm.br"), go.importObject)` I get below error -

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.

How do I load this into my HTML?

Comment: Your HTTP server should provide this file with a `Content-Encoding: br` header so that it gets transparently decompressed by the browser.

Comment: So, if you open up the DevTools console in your browser, what's the MIME type of main.wasm.br file reported by the server?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - The browser doesn't seem to decompress the payload. My server is responding with `Content-Encoding: br`. The browser isn't identifying it. 

Also, I observed that in the request headers browser sends `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`. So I even tried with gzipped response. Still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @kostix - I see `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` and `Content-Encoding: br`. Also to note, this is not happening only for brotli, even gzip has the same behaviour.

Comment: So, I think you should somehow make your server serve these WASM blobs with `Content-Type` `application/wasm`; `Content-Encoding` seems to be fine.

Comment: Thank you @kostix for hinting me towards this. I made relevant NginX changes and was able to crack it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone who commented and directed me towards the solution.

So it simply boils down to understanding the basics of HTTP request/response -

`Content-Type` controls what is the actual data type of response content.

`Content-Encoding` controls what encoding/compression logic have we used to encode the response content.

In my case, I manually compressed the wasm file using gzip and configured NginX as below -

```
location ~ \.wasm {
    default_type 'application/wasm';
    add_header 'Content-Encoding' 'gzip';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
}
```

You can configure your makefile or build script to compress the wasm everytime you build the project.

> Note: I am yet to find a way to request brotli encoding and do similar config for brotli. By default, `fetch` requests with `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip` only. No brotli.